# Proof that convexity implies pseudoconvexity

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

I have two questions.

1. By definition, pseudoconvexity is for functions whose domain is 'convex open' set while convexity is for functions with just 'convex' (not necessarily open) set. Then how does convexity imply pseudoconvexity always? Is it like convexity on a set implies pseudoconvexity on interior of the set, just like continuity on $[a, b]$ implies differentiability on $(a,b)$?
2. Can someone refer me to a book or resource containing the proof for convexity implies pseudoconvexity? I just encountered these definitions in what I am working on and I am not explicitly learning about convex sets and functions, so I do not have a resource to refer to right now, where I can find this proof.

Edit:
I am following this definition for pseudoconvexity: Let $S$ be a nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $S$. The function $f$ is pseudoconvex if, for each $x_1$,$x_2\in S$ with $\nabla{f}(x_1)^T(x_2−x_1)\geq 0$, then $f(x_2)\geq f(x_1)$.

Comment: What is your definition of pseudoconvexity?

Comment: Where did you find this definition of pseudoconvexity? For functions of one variable, it amounts to the assumption of monotonicity, which does not imply convexity of course.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I found this in the Non-linear programming book by Bazaraa et al. Coming to your point, I can see that for a single variable function, if I fix $x_1$, then ahead of $x_1$ the function will be monotone increasing. However, I cannot comment on the behaviour for points before $x_1$ right?

Comment: The point I was making is that for differentiable functions of one variable, monotonicity implies pseudoconvexity, which is why I find this definition odd. But all differentiable convex functions are also pseudoconvex and pseudoconvexity implies that a function is either monotonic or convex, so I see a point of this definition.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not all sources define the "pseudoconvex function" in the same way.

   - [Nonlinear Programming: Theory and Algorithms](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=nDYz-NIpIuEC&lpg=PA1&pg=PT150) by Bazaraa, Sherali and Shetty, and [Invexity and Optimization](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=SDbS50KIQGIC&pg=PA7) by Shashi, Mishra and Giorgi give the same definition you do, which requires the function to be differentiable and its domain to be open, but not necessarily convex. To eliminate ambiguity I shall refer to functions that are pseudoconvex in this sense as *BS-pseudoconvex*.
   - [Iterative Solution of Nonlinear Equations in Several Variables](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=UEFRfUZBpUEC&pg=PA102) by Ortega and Rheinboldt require the domain of pseudoconvexity to be convex, but not necessarily open, and give a definition which does *not* require the function to be differentiable. They say it is "easy to see" that their condition reduces to  to the one in your definition whenever the function is Gateaux differentiable (a weaker condition than full differentiability). The degree to which it is "easy to see" this may well depend on how familiar you are with the relevant concepts.  I shall refer to functions that are pseudoconvex in this sense as *OR-pseudoconvex*.

   $\ $
   It is *not* true that convexity always implies BS-pseudoconvexity (i.e. pseudoconvexity in the sense in which you have defined it), because a convex function is not necessarily differentiable.  What is true in this case is that *if* a convex function is differentiable on the interior of its domain *then* it must be BS-pseudoconvex on that interior.

   It *is* true, however, that convexity always implies OR-pseudoconvexity.
2. I couldn't find a proof in any of the above references that convexity implies pseudoconvexity, merely assertions to that effect.  Starting with Ortega and Rheinboldt's definition, however:

   A function $\ g:D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ is *OR-pseudoconvex* on a convex set $\ D_0\subseteq D\ $ if, whenever $\ g(x) > g(y)\ $, with $\ x,y\in D_0\ $, there exist $\ \alpha>0\ $ and $\ \tau\in(0,1]\ $ (both depending, in general, on $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $) such that
   $$
   g((1-t)x+ty)\le g(x)-t\alpha\ \ \text{ for all }\ t\in[0,\tau]\ ,
   $$
   the proof is not all that difficult.

   Let $\ g:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ be a convex function on the convex set $\ D\subseteq\mathbb{R}\ $ and $\ x,y\in D\ $ such that $\ g(x)>g(y)\ $.  Let $\ \tau=1\ $ and $\ \alpha=g(x)-g(y)\ $.  Then $\ \alpha>0\ $, and if $\ t\in[0,\tau]\ $ then the convexity of $\ g\ $ implies that
   \begin{align}
   g((1-t)x+ty)&\le (1-t)g(x)+tg(y)\\
   &=g(x)-t(g(x)-g(y))\\
   &= g(x)-t\alpha\ ,
   \end{align}
   so $\ g\ $ is OR-pseudoconvex on $\ D\ $.

   Now suppose, in addition, that $\ g\ $ is differentiable on the interior of $\ D\ $.  Then there exists $\ \delta\in(0,1)\ $ such that
   $$
   \left|\frac{g(x+t(y-x)) - g(x)}{t}-\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)\right|<\frac{\alpha}{2}
   $$
   for all $\ t\in(0,\delta)\ $.  Therefore,
   \begin{align}
   \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)&\le \frac{g(x+t(y-x)) - g(x)}{t}+ \frac{\alpha}{2}\\
   &\le-\frac{\alpha}{2}\\
   &<0
   \end{align}
   for any such $\ t\ $.  By the equivalent contrapositive, if $\ x,y\ $ lie in the interior of $\ D\ $ with $\ \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)\ge0\ $, then $\ g(x)\le g(y)\ $, so $\ g\ $ is BS-pseudoconvex on the interior of $\ D\ $.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! There are some parts in the proof for BS-pseudoconvexity which are not clear to me, could you please help me there:

1. Should it have been $x+t(y-x)$ instead?

2. Does the first inequality follow from $g(x+t(y-x))=g(x)+\nabla g(x)^Tt(y-x)+|t(y-x)|\Psi(t(y-x))$ where we can get arbitrarily small $\alpha$ for small enough $t$ because $\Psi$ tends to 0 as its argument tends to zero?

3. In the last inequality, I think you wanted an equation with gradient term and difference term interchanged from what they are in your equation. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, I got $\ y-x\ $ the wrong way round throughout, which I have now hopefully corrected. Apologies for the error. The inequality $$
\left|\frac{g(x+t(y-x)) - g(x)}{t}-\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)\right|<\frac{\alpha}{2}
$$ came from the definition of the Gateaux derivative, but you could also use the second-order Taylor's theorem, as you have suggested.  I think the correction of the $\ x-y\ $ terms to $\ y-x\ $ probably answers your third question. If not, please indicate any of the equations or inequalities you think may still be in error.

Comment: Oh yes, its clear now. Thank you!